# Is this a valid proof that $\displaystyle{\text{T: }\mathbb{R}^m\longmapsto \mathbb{R}^n}$ injective and linear implies $\displaystyle{m \leq n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have come up with this but suspect it's wrong:
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{ {\text{T injective}\Longrightarrow \operatorname{Ker}T = \{\vec{0}\} }  \Longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m = \frac{\mathbb{R}^m }{\operatorname{Ker}T} \simeq \operatorname{Im}T }}$$

$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{\operatorname{Im}T\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\Longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}^m \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \Longrightarrow\left|\mathbb{R}^m\right| \leq \left|\mathbb{R}^n\right| \Longrightarrow \left|m\right| \leq \left|n\right| }}$$

The reason I think this is invalid is because I believe I have seen $\mathbb{R}^m$ is bijective to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all  $\displaystyle{m,n}$, which would mean they have the same cardinality.

I have also been asked to prove that if a linear function $T$ between those sets is surjective then $m \geq n$, and if it is bijective then $m=n$. Any insight is appreciated!

It's my first course in linear algebra so my knowledge is limited. Also first time using Latex, someone can surely format this better.

Comment: Injective and linear implies surjective by the dimension theorem. Hence, $n=m$.

Comment: @alberto injective and linear does not imply surjective

Comment: What? How about $T: \mathbb{R}^1\longmapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ where $T(x) = (x,x)$. This is injective and linear but not surjective. @Alberto

Comment: I see, I overlooked. I had distortioned version of the Rank–nullity theorem in my memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just the last conclusion that is false. Indeed, as you said, $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ have the same cardinality. The cardinality does not say anything about the dimension.

The better way to do this is the following; You've shown that $\mathbb{R}^m \cong \operatorname{Im}T$, so $\dim\mathbb{R}^m = \dim\operatorname{Im}T$. But also $\operatorname{Im}T \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace, so $\dim\operatorname{Im}T\leq \dim\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $m = \dim\mathbb{R}^m \leq \dim\mathbb{R}^n = n$.

**Edit:** To show your statement if $T$ is surjective, you can proceed similarly. This time, however, $\operatorname{Im}T = \mathbb{R}^n$. What can you say about $\frac{\mathbb{R}^m}{\operatorname{Ker}T}$ and its dimension?

Comment: Makes much more sense, thank you! If you don't mind, do you think the part with the quotient space is necessary, or can I just assume $ImT$ is isomorphic to the preimage since T is injective? Similarly, could I assume in the surjective case that $\mathbb{R}^n is isomorphic to the preimage?

Comment: @RealityIsSenseless Note, in the question where you work with $T$ is surjective, you no longer assume $T$ is injective. It goes $\quad$ 
1) $T$ is injective $\implies m \leq n, \;$ 2) $T$ is surjective $\implies m\geq n, \;$ 3) $T$ is bijective $\implies m = n$